# bash terminal scripting for OBDII

Tags: bash, macos, obd-ii

Is it possible to write bash scripts and be able to execute them when the CAN on OBDII is so fast (500 kbit/sec)?

Or the scripting is not a problem at all, but the used interface?

I looked all over this site and internet, but did not find an answer to my question: how to best script medium complex data exchange between mac osx terminal (bash) and OBDII vehicles.

My final program is written in freeRTOS / C language for 32 PIC processor, but is is very awkward to carry so many things to try out protocol questions.

(I hope this question belongs here, if not, I would appreciate it to be directed elsewhere).

Comment: `bash` is most likely unsuitable for this; I assume that the binary data coming from the OBDII port can contain null bytes, and `bash` cannot handle them.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` can only process data in the form of null-terminated strings. As such, it cannot itself handle arbitrary binary data that could contain null bytes.